# Where is the configuration file of the MySQL?

Tags: macos, mysql

As we know, our Mac own a Mysql, under the `/usr/local/mysql`, it is a soft link from `/usr/local/mysql-<mysql-version>-macos<macos-version>`.

But how can I find its configuration file? because in general, the mysql configuration file is named `my.cnf`.

Whether or not the mysql configuration file is under the `/usr/local/mysql/` directory?

I find the directory use `find ../mysql -name my.cnf`

Comment: See this answer on SO:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10757169/mysql-my-cnf-location-on-os-x